# Como adicionar indice em um array

Tags: javascript, array

Estou criando um Array em Javascript no seguinte formato:

```
series = [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7]
            }]
```

Mas em alguns casos, tenho que adicionar novos valores no indice `data`:

```
data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 2.7, 8.9, ...]
```

alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer inserir mais valores numa dessas arrays `data` existentes, ou inserir uma nova cidade na array mais externa?

Comment: Inserir mais valores no array `data`

Comment: Qual? No seu exemplo tem 2.

Comment: tanto faz, quero saber como faz pra inserir mais valores em qualquer um..

Comment: @Thiago se a sua pergunta for mais completa vai ter respostas mais completas e exatas. Como quer alterar a array? Um a um? ou como consequência de outro código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu podes utilizar o método [push()](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/) do javascript para fazer o que pretendes.

Por exemplo, tendo o teu array:

```
series = [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5]
}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7]
}]
```

Se quiseres adicionar um elemento em cada `data`, percorres o array num `.each()` e adicionas o que queres. Algo como:

```
    $.each(series, function (index, itemData) {
       itemData.data.push(12);
    });
```

Deixo aqui [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/rHEC4/) para veres. Neste exemplo estou a adicionar `12` no `data`

Comment: `.push()` não seria um método do Javascript? Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Sim fui verificar e é do javascript. Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 4):

Você pode adicionar novos valores, usando o **`.push()`**:

```
series[1].data.push(5)
series[1].data
2014-08-01 13:00:41.524[-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 5]
```